# How to use a FormView with Entity Data Model?

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework, formview

I made a `FormView` connected to a `SqlDataSource` for adding and updating records, but now I'm trying to use an entity data model and LINQ instead:

```cs
FormView.DataSource = Model.Table.Where(t => t.ID == IdFromQueryString);
```

The page works up to the point where I load a record and I can see the `EditItemTemplate`, and it's all filled in with the right values. But when I try to update the record, it throws an unhandled `ItemUpdating` event, which never happened with the `SqlDataSource`.

So I add an `ItemUpdating` handler, which the `FormView` calls, and I can see that the correct parameters are being passed in. However, the `FormView` never changes the database itself, and `ItemUpdated` is never called.

Does this mean I have to fill in `ItemInserting`, `ItemUpdating`, etc. myself so they call the databases (probably using stored procedures)? If so, how can I trigger the `ItemInserted` and `ItemUpdated` events? Or, is there a way the `FormView` can automatically provide this functionality based on the data model?